# Is it possible to display a google calendar in a kivy app?

Tags: kivy

I am trying to make an app as a school project/hobby with kivy, but I am struggling with how to add a google calendar display in the kivy app. I want to be able to display a google calendar and link it as well. I understand the API and how to add events using python, but I don't know how to display the calendar.

Comment: There isn't an existing calendar widget, so you will have to make one. If you have a specific question about doing so, I suggest asking that.

Comment: I want to use google calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [kivyMD](https://github.com/heattheatr/kivymd/) library that has a [`Date Picker`](https://github.com/heattheatr/kivymd/wiki/Components-Date-Picker) widget.
There is a mini [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALtocQRMNPk) too..